# Wordpress how to add menu to admin section and have access to all other admin

Tags: php, wordpress

Can anyone please help me?

i have installed a word press and i have created a sub menu by name Manufacturer and have created a page but the page is accessed only in admin user but not with the other admin user which i have created. how to give access permission to that admin users?
i am a beginner to php as well as word press please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin..

[wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)

Answer (score 0):

When you create the admin panel page, you should give the proper permissions to the users, who you want to access it. For example:

```
<?php add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position ); ?>
```

So the important thing here is the `$capability`. The `$capability` is string and is **required** for this menu to be displayed to the user. User levels are deprecated and should not be used here!
So the possible capabilities for regular users (i.e. Author and Contributor) are:

**Author**

- delete_posts
- delete_published_posts
- edit_posts
- edit_published_posts
- publish_posts
- read
- upload_files

**Contributor**

- delete_posts
- edit_posts
- read

Use one of them when creating your admin page. Read more [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).